# Is ADO the only way to communicate with SQL Server from WebForms using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using a WEbForms front end and C# code to call a SQL Server Stored Procedure (SP) to execute an exhaustive search on many fields based on the options selected in the form.  The SP has multiple "optional" parameters that are all set to "NULL" on definition.

```
@keyword1 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@keyword2 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@keyword3 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@keyword4 nvarchar(50) = NULL,
```

I'm being TOLD by one of the "front end" developers that the ONLY way to call this SP is to use ADO and to specify EVERY parameter passing in the variables as NULL where there is no data.

In other posts on here, I see a command similar to 
    param.add(@paramName, dataType).value = "paramValue"

The question is, do I have to add a parameter to the command for all of those that are NULL or do I just pass in the value pair that is NOT NULL?

The second question is, is there a better way (than ADO) to do this?

Thanks in advance
Bob

I should say that it works passing in all of the NULLs, but I'm looking for efficiency.

Comment: I do not believe that you're limited to only ADO.Net for SP calls, Entity Framework supports them as well as other light weight ORM's such as Dapper.

Comment: If your stored procedure has the parameters defined as you posted here then those parameters have default values in your stored procedures. In other words, those are the values to supply to that variable if the parameter is not included in the procedure call. This is one of the big advantages to having named parameters in a database call.

Comment: Why is a front-end developer dictating what must happen on the back-end?  *scratches head*  Shouldn't you be talking to one of the back-end developers instead about what is required?

Comment: Even if you're using classic ADO (let alone ADO.NET), this statement is false. You can execute the query `EXEC Procedure` as a query, giving it no parameters, and the procedure call will use the default values for the optional parameters.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Adding an ORM will add some overhead to the execution of the query. The OP asks for the most optimal way to execute his statement.

Comment: @billybob _"is there a better way (than ADO) to do this"_ doesn't preclude using an ORM at all.

Comment: @Amy, exactly... but I'm the BE developer... they tell me talking to myself is "bad" and want to lock me away... LOL

Comment: Answering the question in the headline: You could also use ODBC with you definitely should not do. OLE DB is quite good. But as you are on .NET, why not just use .net database providers? I'd recommend it

Comment: @JeroenMostert, that's what I have been led to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and answers.  What I'm reading is ADO is probably the better option for efficiency and that I need to find a new front end developer... LOL